# .htaccess redirect loop when trying to transform last part of URL to fragment

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following rule in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule ^(segment1|segment2)/(.*)$ $1/#$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

The intent is to prepend a `#` to the last part of the URL. But I run into a redirect loop issue. I don't know why as I applied `L` flag.

What I want to achieve is, for example:

Turn:

`http://example.com/segment1/test`

into:

`http://example.com/segment1/#test`

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tested in Debian/Apache2:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(segment1|segment2)/([^#]+)$ /$1/#$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

The [L] flag only ends the current run of rewrite, as URI changes, it will continue to rewrite, so you've an infinite loop.